# Call to undefined function iconv_get_encoding()

Tags: magento, zend-framework, cron

In my System, PHP version is 5.6.32
Cron is running and Found message in cron_schedule table like below:

```
TRIGGER: shutdown function
Last error: 
Array
(
    [type] => 1
    [message] => Call to undefined function iconv_get_encoding()
    [file] => /home/fanfan/public_html/lib/Zend/Validate/Hostname.php
    [line] => 1110
)

Backlog: 
exception 'Exception' in /home/fanfan/public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Helper/GracefulDead.php:53
```

I have checked and Found iconv is installed in my system.[Check attachment please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58XG3.png)

```
            $origenc = PHP_VERSION_ID < 50600
                        ? iconv_get_encoding('internal_encoding')
                        : ini_get('default_charset');
            if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 50600) {
                iconv_set_encoding('internal_encoding', 'UTF-8');
            } else {
                ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

make sure your current php.ini contains:

```
extension=iconv.so
```

and check if `iconv` extension is installed.

you can check it it phpinfo with

```
php -i | grep -i "iconv support"
```

Comment: Already installed. Please check attachment added in Question.  thanks

Comment: Aoe Scheduler runs from cron. and cron runs php cli, that has separate php.ini. So check if iconv enabled in php cli

Comment: Checked with Write log File and Found all function loaded that is related with iconv extention. Not have root access so can't able to check cli php.ini.